# Kotin: Is `until` and `..` just a syntax difference?

Tags: kotlin

Does `for(i in 0 until limit)` and `for(i in 0..limit)` make any difference on how the algorithm behaves or is it only a syntax difference like `.forEach()` is the same as a for loop?

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/ranges.html#progression

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are not quite the same `0..limit` yields all values between 0 and `limit` *including `limit`* while the `until` variant excludes the upper bound.

For example `for(i in 1..4)` will have `i` have values 1, 2, 3, and 4 while `for(i in 1 until 4)` would have `i` have only the values 1, 2, and 3.

Comment: `until` is equivalent to the still-experimental but eventual preferred usage `..<` "range until" operator.